# understanding javascript closures with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

i've started learning about javascript closures, and while experimenting, i realised that the following code does not work as expected:

```
(function($){
    var p='<p style="color:red">12345</p>';
    $p=$(p);
    $("body").append($p);
    $p.appendTo($("body"));
    console.log($p);
})(jQuery)
```

in the console, i can see the jquery object being returned, but its not being appended to the body (i have tried both the append and appendto methods).

can someone please explain to me why this code does not work as expected?

i had a thought: this may have been because jquery is not loaded by the time this function is called, however, the jquery object IS being output to the console, so that must mean jquery IS loaded at the time that this function is called.

can any knowledgeable person shed some light?

Comment: Works for me? - http://jsfiddle.net/yUJ48/

Comment: The jsfiddle works because it inserts the script into an onLoad block, so the body element is available. If you change the fiddle to "no wrap (head)" you can reproduce the issue (http://jsfiddle.net/yUJ48/1/). The script is running immediately, before the page has been declared. David has the answer.

Comment: $p=$(p); ?? Why? Also why always using $p?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `body` is available when the script is executed, you can do that using the shorthand domready callback:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var p = '<p style="color:red">12345</p>';
    $p = $(p).appendTo(document.body);
    console.log($p);
});
```

Comment: I really don't see the need for $p all the time.
`jQuery(function($){
    var p = $('<p style="color:red">12345</p>');
    p.appendTo($("body"));
});`
Would have worked just fine as well

Comment: @omarello or just `$('<p style="color:red">12345</p>').appendTo(document.body);` but the question was not about optimizing the code....

Comment: i feel very stupid right now. ofcourse! the body is not ready!
thanks David!
@omarello, the $p was residue from some other testing, and i just wanted to understand the core issue, and not optimize it, as David has correctly pointed out.